# Dataflow 1.2.0 YAML configuration changes

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Yesterday I upgraded my development environment to Spring Cloud Dataflow 1.2.0 and all of my sink/source apps dependencies.

I have two main issues:

javaOpts: -Xmx128m is not longer being picked up, so locally deployed apps have the default Xmx value.

Here is the format of my previously working Dataflow yaml config.

```
See full here: https://pastebin.com/p1JmLnLJ
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      applicationProperties:
        stream:
          spring:
            cloud:
              deployer:
                local:
                  javaOpts: -Xmx128m
```

Kafka config options like ssl.truststore.location etc. are not being read correctly. Another stackoverflow post indicated these must be marked like this "[ssl.truststore.location]". Is there some documented working yaml config or list of breaking changes with 1.2.0? The file based authentication block was also moved, and I was able to figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It looks like a bug in [Spring Cloud Local Deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/commits/master/spring-cloud-deployer-local/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/JavaCommandBuilder.java) to consider the common application properties passed via `args`. Created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/48 to track this.